# Python code for gcloud beta services identity create --service=$api --project=$project_id

Tags: python, bash, unix, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a bash code for gcp identity creation as below :

gcloud beta services identity create --service=$api --project=$project_id

I need corresponding python code, I have tried the below code but it is throwing exception

```
def generateServiceIdentity(self, services):
        service = discovery.build(
            'serviceusage', 'v1', credentials=self.credentials)
        
        request = service.services().generateServiceIdentity(parent=services)
        response = request.execute()
        return response
```

This is throwing the below exception :

Exception occured:'Resource' object has no attribute 'generateServiceIdentity' while trying to executing ..

Thanks

Comment: This is not fancy, but you can put the command inside `os.system('command here')` to run it in Python.

Comment: I didn't get that , sorry. In this case what command would go inside os.system() ?

Comment: 1. `import os` 2. `os.system('gcloud beta services identity create --service={} --project={}'.format(api,project_id))`

Comment: It got executed without any error and seems like it worked. Thanks for the quick help. I will update if there is any issues while proceeding.  But my assumption was to use python gcp libraries for specific functionalities. Can I follow the same for policy binding also ?

Comment: I think so. You can use any gcloud command inside `os` or any Linux CLI command

Comment: use --log-http to see the detail of gcloud API calls. Then reproduce the API calls with your code.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can run `gcloud` inside Python's `os` library:

```
import os 
os.system('gcloud beta services identity create --service={} --project={}'.format(api,project_id))
```

Comment: Thank you for the command. But I was trying to implement this using discovery API rather than using python os library.